# How to backup a User Library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 100+ jars in a project. I have manually defined the source jar location for most of them so that the javadoc becomes conveniently available within the IDE.

Now, if I have to configure the IDE on a different machine, I don't want to go through the whole process again.

Can I backup the User Library definition and import it in another instance of Eclipse?

Workarounds are welcome as long as they make javadoc available within Eclipse and don't require repeated manual work of linking source jar for each jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse Select Window -> Preferences. In Preferences Dialog select Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries. In the right side list select your library and Export it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use a tool such as Maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: This is possibly the long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences

Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> buttons Import and Export

Comment: Cool, I was probably not paying attention. I thought it was only for importing jars in to the library.